# Checking for time complexity of a code

Tags: python, time-complexity

```
def sort_list(lst):
    result = []
    result.append(lst[0])
    for i in range(1,len(lst)):
        insert_list(lst[i], result)
    return result

def insert_list(x, lst):
    a = search(x, lst)
    lst.insert(a, x)
    return lst

def search(x, seq):
    for i in seq: 
        if x<i:
            return seq.index(i)
        elif x == i:
            return seq.index(i)
        elif x>seq[-1]:
            return (seq.index(seq[-1]))+1
```

Is the time complexity of this code O(n)?

Comment: What is `insert_list`?

Comment: oh ya i forgot to define. Sorry about that.

Comment: Now you didn't define `search`.

Comment: i tried to define but the progam doesn't allow me to. It says there's too much coding

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the complexity of 'insert_list'. In this case, since insert_list is inside a for-loop, the complexity would be n*(complexity of insert_list).

Answer (score 0):

If you take n unit of time for the loop as there are n elements inside the list and one unit time for each remaining steps. The total time taken is 1+1+n*(time for insert_list )+1 = n*(time for insert_list) + 3.

Again, the time complexity further depends on insert_list step.

Consider this step,

> a = search(x, lst)

It has two parts, search and assignment.
Lets take linear search. its time complexity is O(n).
so for insert_list function time taken is (search)+(assign)+(insert) = n+1+1 = n+2

So the total time taken = n*(n+2)+3 = n^2+2n+3

Since O(n) is an asymptotic notation, n is taken as a very large value. In that case 2n and 3 can be omitted. So time complexity is O(n^2), which is a *polynomial time complexity*.

Comment: _Yes the time complexity is log(n)_: should be O(n), I think